# where is the scipy.optimize function or module?

Tags: optimization, scipy

I wanna using optimization method in `scipy` but. it failed.

I make the simple code,

```
import scipy as sp 

def f1p(x):
    return 2 * (x - 2)
result = sp.optimize.minimize(f1, x0, jac=f1p)
print(result)
```

but the error raise.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-435b98a570a0> in <module>()
----> 1 result = sp.optimize.minimize(f1, x0, jac=f1p)
      2 print(result)
      3 scipy.optimize.minimize

AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'optimize'

this link[enter link description here][1], official scipy documentation also said `scipy.optimize` can be used.
```

I don't know why I happened. and I wanna know where it is?

Comment: what is your scipy version?

Comment: it is most recent version. because I installed it yesterday.

Comment: Why not follow the [tutorial](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/optimize.html)? So here: ```from scipy.optimize import minimize```. Somewhere in the docs is also a warning/explanation of the module system in regards to how to import. **edit**: probably [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html).

Comment: ah.......thx...I don't know that. `from scipy.optimize import minimize` works. thx.

Comment: ```import scipy.optimize as opt``` followed by ```opt.minimize``` works too. Make sure to read my edited (second) link.

Comment: @sascha: probably best to add it as an answer so that it disappears on the unanswered list.